# file_put_contents() succeeds but no file created

Tags: php

I use `file_put_contents()` all the time, but this time it is failing.

It returns non-FALSE, which is should indicate the number of bytes written, but **no file is actually generated.**

(and it says 20 bytes were written for a 7-character string)

```
$ php --interactive
php > print realpath("/etc/php.d");
/etc/php.d
php > $n = file_put_contents("yo baby", "/etc/php.d/dvmon.ini");
php > print $n;
20
php > exit
$ ls -l /etc/php.d/d*
ls: cannot access /etc/php.d/d*: No such file or directory
```

The permissions are wide open:

```
$ ls -ld /etc
drwxrwxrwx. 128 root root 12288 Feb  9 05:19 /etc
$ ls -ld /etc/php.d
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Feb  9 05:46 /etc/php.d
```

Comment: So you've created a file called `yo baby` in the current directory, with the content `/etc/php.d/dvmon.ini` (your 20 bytes response from the function call)..... __order of arguments to functions is important__

Answer (score 2):

The order of parameters is the opposite. First file comes, then the content:

```
$n = file_put_contents("/etc/php.d/dvmon.ini", "yo baby");
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameters are reversed.

Not enough coffee.